# Queries regarding file upload to Google Drive using API

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-drive-api, google-drive-shared-drive

I have the following queries:

1. We have a GCP organization with 500+ projects. How do I find out which GCP project(s) are our company's shared Google drives mapped to?
2. I need to upload files to our company's shared drive. I'll be using the following Drive API (https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/create). What IAM role should my service account have?
3. Do I need to delegate domain-wide authority to my service account?

Please advise. Thanks.

Comment: if you have a workspace account you need to set up domain wide delegation.  If you want to upload to a specific directory you can share it with the service account email address and then it will be able to upload to it.    Doing a file.list with the service account will tell you what it has access to.

Comment: Thanks for the response. But which IAM role shall I assign my service account to begin with? Also, how do I know - to which GCP project shall I restrict the IAM role to?